# InternalClientWebSocket instance cannot be used for communication because it has been transitioned into the 'Aborted' state

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I have an exception when I try to receive data from more than three websockets. If I try on only one, two or three websockets it works perfectly.
I get the exception in this line:

```
tasks.Add(Send(webSocket, "11"));
```

The exception message:

> Exception: System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The
>   'System.Net.WebSockets.InternalClientWebSocket' instance cannot be
>   used for communication because it has been transitioned into the
>   'Aborted' state. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation
>   was canceled.    at
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
>   at
>   System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.d__21.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.d__45.MoveNext()
>   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfAborted(Boolean aborted,
>   Exception innerException)    at
>   System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String
>   methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
>   Boolean aborted)    at
>   System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.d__45.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RTLS_GetData_From_WebSockets.App_Code;

namespace RTLS_GetData_From_WebSockets
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object consoleLock = new object();
        private const int sendChunkSize = 256;
        private const int receiveChunkSize = 256;
        private const bool verbose = true;
        private static readonly TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000);

        private static WebSocket client;
        const string host = "ws://localhost:8080";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Connect(host).Wait();
        }

        public static async Task Connect(string uri)
        {
            ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;

            try
            {
                webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);

                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                tasks.Add(Receive(webSocket));

                tasks.Add(Send(webSocket, "9"));
                tasks.Add(Send(webSocket, "10"));
                tasks.Add(Send(webSocket, "11"));

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (webSocket != null)
                    webSocket.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine();

                lock (consoleLock)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }

        static UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

        private static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket webSocket, string ZoneID)
        {
            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("{\"method\":\"subscribe\", \"resource\":\"/zones/" + ZoneID + "\"}");

            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                LogStatus(false, buffer, buffer.Length);
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[receiveChunkSize];
            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    LogStatus(true, buffer, result.Count);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void LogStatus(bool receiving, byte[] buffer, int length)
        {
            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = receiving ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Gray;

                if (verbose)
                {
                    string tmp = encoder.GetString(buffer);                   
                    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Zones>(tmp);
                    Console.WriteLine(data.body.status); 
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }
}


    [DataContract]
    public class Zones
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "body")]
        public ZoneBody body { get; set; }
    }

    public class ZoneBody
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "feed_id")]
        public string feed_id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "zone_id")]
        public string zone_id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "at")]
        public string at { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `ClientWebSocket` doesn't support parallel send, so who knows what happens when you are trying to send multiple messages in parallel to it. And anyway - why? Send them one by one, doing that in parallel doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Evk Thank you for your advice, it helped me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from MSDN, here is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.sendasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This operation will not block. The returned Task object will complete
>   after the send request on the ClientWebSocket instance has completed.
>
> Exactly one send and one receive is supported on each ClientWebSocket
>   object in parallel.

Call your Connect method one by one.

Comment: Glad I help you.