# C# ClientWebSocket doen't receive incoming messages until an outbound message is sent

Tags: c#, websocket, ws

I'm trying to receive messages from a server in real time, ideally using the `ClientWebSocket` class. I would like to both send and receive messages on their own. Unfortunately, I always first have to send an outgoing message through `WebSocket.SendAsync()` and only then new messages arrive with `WebSocket.ReceiveAsync()`. I tried searching and debugging the code but couldn't find anything that would fix this wrong behavior.

I would like to receive the incoming messages independently of me sending anything. Any help is be appreciated.

```
    public static void WebsocketReceive()
    {
        while (WebSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[2048];

            int offset = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    ArraySegment<byte> bytesReceived = new(receiveBuffer, offset, receiveBuffer.Length);

                    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, source.Token);
                    offset += result.Count;

                    if (result.EndOfMessage) break;
                }
                catch { break; };
            }

            if (offset != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, offset));
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: more code

This is where I initialize the WebSocket and connect to a server. I don't have access to their code.

```cs
WebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
await WebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://example.com"), Source.Token);
```

After connecting, I run my `WebsocketReceive()` method to start collecting incoming messages.

I send messages into the `WebSocket` from a different method, through this code:

```cs
await WebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("message to post")), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, Source.Token);
```

I should also provide some more details about how the client and server interact. At the start, I send and receive a few responses, which somehow works. I send some messages and receive responses, which are printed into the console.

What isn't working is specifically when the server wants to send me a message on its own. After a few seconds, I should receive incoming events from the server. This is where it stops printing into the console. Whenever I send any message again all of them come back at once - the loop is repeated for all messages in the "queue".

Comment: I think the problem is outside. Here you receive an entire message and the reason why you aren't receiving more messages is in other methods. Can you post more code? The part in which you send and receive. Maybe that part of the code is programmed doing a send and then a receive and another send...

Comment: And for this receive, when can receive multiple messages, take in mind that you can receive the end of one message and some part of the next message.

Comment: @Victor I edited the post with more information. I'm not running ReceiveAsync() anywhere else in the code.

Comment: The problem is not in the send o receive, that is working. Are you sending and receiving in the same thread?

Comment: @Victor They are not within the same thread. How would I even do that?

Comment: That's ok. You need in different threads. It's another thing. Do you have a small sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Victor I made a little example that will allow you to reproduce the issue. I also made the server part to make it easier to use. Every 2 seconds an event is supposed to be received and logged.

Code:
https://mega.nz/folder/1jwyhIbB#OkkzHBp6KZRPMOti4ryD8g(

Comment: The problem is that server is sending more than one message without a response. Check this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/49729910/18452174.

Comment: I don't understand how that is causing any problems. In the real application, the server isn't expecting me to respond to the events, so I can't do that. Perhaps something is wrong in my response awaiting function?